# Determine Frequency Resolution samples

Tags: frequency, continuous-signals

Can someone tell me if the way I solved this problem is right?

Suppose I have a signal $X_a(t)= 0.5cos(700πt)+0.6cos(720πt)+0.1cos(780πt)$ where $F_s=8000Hz$

I want to determine the minimum samples which must be available in order the frequency resolution of DFT be ok.

I did this:

- Firstly calculate each frequency of the signal:
  $F_1=350Hz$, $F_2=360Hz$, $F_3=390Hz$
- Calculate the differences: $F_2$-$F_1$=$10Hz$ ,$F_3$-$F_2$= $30Hz$ , $F_3$-$F_1$= $40Hz$
- $ΔF_{min}$=$10Hz$
- $ΔF$ = $ \frac{f_s}{N} $, so $N\geq\frac{8000Hz}{10}$=800 samples

Can someone tell me if my solution is right and explain why we choose the minimum difference

Thanks

Comment: It could be argued that you need 5 Hz resolution rather than 10 Hz, otherwise F1, F2 will appear in adjacent bins and will be indistinguishable from a single peak that straddles both bins.

Comment: @PaulR I don't understand my answer is right?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "right". ;-) I would say that your peaks in the frequency domain need to be at least two bins apart, in order for them to be distinct, in which case you would need 5 Hz resolution, not 10 Hz.

Comment: @jojek I have seen you 've experience in this topic for similar threads which you have give answers, could you help me  If my thought is wrong/right?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually considered difficult to resolve a pair of adjacent frequencies unless there is dip between the two FFT peaks.  Depending on the window (rectangular or otherwise) and how much of a dip you require between the two peaks to consider them resolved (above some floor), and whether or what kind of result interpolation you use, you will need from a bit less than double to triple or more of your suggested 800 FFT result bins.

Of course in a-priori zero noise, your signal of 3 pure sinusoids has 9 free parameters, so you might be able to determine your 3 input frequencies with perhaps as few as 9 or a bit more non-aliased samples.  In any case, much less than 800.

The resolution of a single isolated frequency peak above a low enough noise floor to the nearest 10Hz can likely be done using far fewer than 800 samples by using interpolation methods on the FFT result, depending on the SNR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so if I want the minimum samples which must be available in order the frequency resolution of DFT is sufficient is my answer right? I have found this formula in a signal processing book, in book is used the minimum diference but don't explain why.. that is I don't understand which frequency must put in  denominator